# scroll and click element in appium

Tags: android, scroll, appium

```
String Organization = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"textName\").instance(0));
driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(Organization)).click();
```

**I'm trying to scroll down till the element it is scrolling but not clickable**

Answer (score 0):

```
String Organization = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("textName").instance(0))"; 

driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(Organization));

driver.findElement(By.id("Your_Selector_ID")).click();
```